# Searching for a tag doesn't give the best options

Tags: discussion, tag-search

I am asking a question for the first time on SE after a very long layoff, and I was unsure which site would be the best place for me to ask it. So, like a good citizen, I went to the main StackExchange site and [searched](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bproxmox%5D) for the tag. Because it was related to hardware, I knew that it should likely go into [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but I wanted to verify that nothing had changed in my time away. I was more than a little surprised that the first page of results were all sending me back to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), the programming oriented site.

Should certain tags be flagged for certain sites? Is this a topic that had been discussed before?

Comment: What you've (unfortunately) learned is that *a lot of off-topic questions get asked on Stack Overflow*. This is why looking at the current list of questions is not a very good way of determining what is on-topic for that site. The better way is to read the Help Center, specifically the `https://sitename.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic` page.

Comment: *"Should certain tags be flagged for certain sites?"* Although a specific tag by itself *might* be off-topic in solitude for [so], for example a question with just [tag:facebook] is probably off topic, when combined with others they likely aren't. Using the prior example, if the question is also about trying to use the APIs with .Net code, and the OP demonstrates why what they have isn't working it's perfectly on topic. Some tags are very likely completely off-topic regardless, but these are the small minority. In these cases, the tag wiki normally denotes this as well.

Comment: As Cody Gray has pointed out, you've discovered the snowball effect of Stack Overflow: there's a critical mass of users posting random crap on this site and that confuses new users, which results in more random crap.  Also, if you weren't confused enough yet, this post probably belongs on [metase] because it applies to all sites, not just Stack Overflow.  How are you supposed to know that?  No clue.

Comment: Pretty much anything that can be posted on Meta Stack Exchange can also be posted here on Meta Stack Overflow, @CharlieArmstrong, so that's not really a distinction that we expect users to worry about. If something truly needs to be migrated between the Meta sites, the volume of questions is small enough that moderators can do so. And usually would only need to be migrated for moderation reasons, e.g., we want to close it as a duplicate of a prior discussion. (Obviously, I completely agree with the *rest* of your comment.)

Comment: Adding to @Cody 's point the list of tags is also not representative of what's on topic on one site. Tags can (and do) have different meanings in different sites. The presence of a tag isn't determinant of the topicality of any question, even if it's related to the tag, on the site.

Comment: My usual point of reference on where I should ask something is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on

Comment: The more fruitful way to search for something on Stack Exchange is like <https://duckduckgo.com/?q=proxmox+site%3Asuperuser.com> (or a different search engine if you have one that you're training).

Comment: Searching for something on Stack Exchange using Stack Exchange's own search engine, is an exercise in pain. (See also: duplicate question search in close screen.) Just avoid doing it.